# Модернизировать фильтр PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

Всех приветствую. Есть код фильтра Wordpress, добавляющий слова в заголовки страниц записей. Фильтр работает не до конца правильно, добавляя слова и в другие заголовки постов на странице. Возможно ли исправить фильтр, чтобы он правильно работал? Спасибо!

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_text_to_page_title' );
function add_text_to_page_title( $title ) {

  if ( in_the_loop() && is_single()) {
    $title = 'Этот пост про '. $title;
  }

  return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать с дополнительной проверкой на main_query

```
add_action('loop_start', function ($q)
{
    if($q->is_main_query()){
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_text_to_page_title', 10, 2);
    } else{
        remove_filter('the_title','add_text_to_page_title', 10, 2);
    }
});

function add_text_to_page_title( $title ) {

  if ( is_single()) {
    $title = 'Этот пост про '. $title;
  }

  return $title;
}
```

Comment: Топ! Всё заработало. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете проверять на конкретный тип записи, в данном примере это `post`, если вам нужно другой тип записи вы можете заменить его на необходимый

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'add_text_in_main_query' );
function add_text_in_main_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_text_to_page_title' );
    } else {
        remove_filter( 'the_title', 'add_text_to_page_title' );
    }
}

function add_text_to_page_title( $title ) {
    return  is_singular( 'post' ) ?  'Этот пост про ' . $title : $title;
}
```

Comment: это неправильный ответ. этот код заменит все заголовки на странице записей. нужно в коде делать проверку на main_query

Comment: К сожалению Ваш код меняет и другие заголовки, но спасибо за попытку!

Comment: @DarthKYL это неправильный ответ. is_main_query() так не используют